# Why does my ArrayList item get converted to an object in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am trying to get an element from my `ArrayList` by it's position.  I keep getting an error message saying "`Object cannot be converted to a string`" on the line that gets the `ArrayList` element.

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList resources = new ArrayList();

resources.add("Brick");
resources.add("Brick");
resources.add("Brick");
resources.add("Wool");
resources.add("Wool");
resources.add("Wool");
resources.add("Wool");
resources.add("Lumber");
resources.add("Lumber");
resources.add("Lumber");
resources.add("Lumber");
resources.add("Stone");
resources.add("Stone");
resources.add("Stone");
resources.add("Wheat");
resources.add("Wheat");
resources.add("Wheat");
resources.add("Wheat");
resources.add("Wasteland");

long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(resources, new Random(seed));

for(int i = 0; i < resources.size(); i++){
    String randomResource = resources.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Use `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: That did the trick!  If you post an answer with this, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `resources` to be of type `ArrayList`, which is a raw type, so `resources.get(i)` returns an instance of type `Object`, which cannot be assigned to a `String` variable.

In order for `resources.get(i)` to return a `String`, change its type to `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use generics for proper type resolving:

```
ArrayList<String> resources = new ArrayList<String>();
```

in you code you've created a list of Object.

Also you can put class cast into `resource.get` line,

```
String randomResource = (String)resources.get(i);
```

but in this case you can get `ClassCastException` in runtime if someone passed different object into your list.

For example:

```
ArrayList resources = new ArrayList();
resources.add(1); <-- this is also allowed because Integer is instance of Object

for(int i = 0; i < resources.size(); i++){
        String randomResource = (String)resources.get(i); <-- ClassCastException because Integer isn't instance of String 

    }
```

More information about generics in java: [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html)